# Is there a way to fix the Invalid Session error?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server

I've been watching videos on youtube of "how to fix minecraft error invalid session" but none of them can help me cause  I don't have them. Could anyone please help me fix this in an easy way? Or is there no way?

Comment: Can you tell us what problems you are having?

Answer (score 1):

When you open the launcher, it connects to the login servers and generates a session ID in exchange for your user login details. Then, whenever you connect to a game server, the login server matches the last session ID it got when you logged in to your game's session ID. However, these session IDs are only for one use (hence "session"), so they expire after a certain amount of time.

To get a new session ID, simply close all instances of the game and the launcher, then start the launcher again.

I know restarting the launcher works, I have to do it occasionally. However the session ID explanation may be somewhat incorrect or out of date. Feel free to correct.

Answer (score 0):

Invalid session can occur, when:

- Your game from launcher is started too fast - before launcher could contact servers and get session ID from them. It is usually fast, but not instant. Usually you can see the button "Play offline", however that might not correspond sometimes (for example if you close the game and restart it too fast that the button don't have time to show properly)
- You launched another launcher/same launcher second times and your original session got rewritten. OR somebody else uses your credentials and does that. If you suspect this, you should take actions to secure your account. Remember, that you are not allowed to trade nor give your credentials to anyone. If you launch game more times, only the latest will have the right Session ID.
- You use some unofficial launcher, then you should use the official ones.
- MC servers borked up... (you can check status of servers for example [here](http://xpaw.ru/mcstatus/))

Session ID is assigned when you launch the game, thus in most cases, **restarting the game** completely (for sure even with launcher) fixes the issue.